# AJAX Queue with retryWhen sending wrong payload on subsequent requests

Tags: angular, ajax, rxjs

I'm using Angular and RXJS and I need a way to send up to 5 AJAX requests at a time, with each request being tried up to 3 times before aborting the request and returning an error. I mostly have it working, but subsequent requests are getting the wrong payload.

Example: Request 1 gets sent with ID: 1  as part of the payload. Request 2 - 5 also get sent (with ID set as 2 - 5 respectively). Request 1 fails and tries again, but the ID that gets sent is 5 (the last request to be sent).

I tried moving everything to a closure thinking that was the problem, but it didn't fix the issue. What's the right way go about implementing something like this? Here's some pseudo code of what I have that is close to what I need.

```
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  timer(i * 1500).subscribe(() => {
    this.sendVideoForProcessing();
  });
}

// Use retryWhen to retry each request up to 3 times
private sendVideoForProcessing() {
  const idToProcess = id; // More happenig behind the scenes to get the next Id from the queue.

  let payload = {'data': this.finalOptions};

  payload['data']['Id'] = idToProcess;

  this.http
    .post(`${this.baseUrl}`, payload)
    .pipe(
      retryWhen(
        err$ => err$.pipe(
          mergeMap((err, i) => {
            if (i > 1) {
              return throwError(err);
            } else {
              return timer(1000);
            }
         }))),
       )
       .subscribe(
         (response: any) => {//do something with response},
         (error: HttpErrorResponse) => {//error},
         () => {
           // Done running if successful
         });
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Maybe the same `this.finalOptions` reference is used in each function call. What happens if you do this instead? - `let payload = {'data': { ...this.finalOptions }};`

Comment: That was it, thank you! This was the reason I moved the function to a closure, but I guess it was still getting the wrong reference. Thanks so much Andrei!

Comment: I'm glad I could help! Is it okay if I add it as an answer?

Comment: Yes, please do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same `this.finalOptions` reference is used in each function call, so this should fix it:

```js
let payload = {'data': { ...this.finalOptions }};
```